# Two different pages/files in the .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

I'm getting to know more about `.htaccess`, Apache & httpd config file.  I have 2 files:

- `index.php`
- `page.php`

Both in the same folder

I already succeed to rewrite the `index.php?site=` to `example.com/sitename`. But when I try to add a rewrite which has to look like `example.com/sitename/article/2` which redirects to `page.php?site=sitename&page=pageid`,
the rewrite does not work. I think this is because of the previous redirect `example.com/sitename`

But I like to have them both in my `.htaccess` file.

My current code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/+]+)$ index.php?site=/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/+]+)$ index.php?site=/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/+]+)$ index.php?site=/$1/Article/&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

As you can see in the last code example I added has to go to:

`example.com/Sitename/Article/2`

Comment: So show us what you actually tried then.

Comment: It of course makes absolutely no sense, to have two RewriteRules matching on the _exact same_ pattern, and expecting them to achieve two different things. As soon as your first `^([a-zA-Z0-9-/+]+)$` pattern matches, _that_ rewrite is performed, and then nothing else any more, since you said this should be the `L` last thing to do. You want to match two distinctly _different_ sorts of URLs - so write two distinctive patterns as well.

Comment: I edited your terminology.  A "redirect" changes the URL for the user.  That isn't what is happening here.  You are using rewrites that change how the URL is handled without making those changes visible to the user.

Comment: So can someone maybe tell what to do?